# Has anyone had an offer rescinded after accepting?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, contract

A few days ago I asked when an offer is considered official (see [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/181031/at-what-point-is-an-offer-official?noredirect=1#comment485934_181031)) and the consensus seemed to be that nothing is official until a contract is signed.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone has had an offer rescinded after accepting it via email? Or why the "distrust"?

Please don't take this as a judgment, I am genuinely curious about how pervasive this is.

Comment: Occasional and not pervasive. Generally would require a serious cause. Changes in available funding. Misconduct by applicant discovered late. But not chaotic. Occasionally a complete department is eliminated, though hopefully with more notice.

Comment: https://theprofessorisin.com/2012/01/03/job-market-horror-stories-part-i-the-rescinded-offer/

Comment: https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2014/03/13/lost-faculty-job-offer-raises-questions-about-negotiation-strategy

Comment: The offer is independent of the contract being signed. Signing a contract is accepting the offer. I can't imagine anyone accepting an offer via e-mail. How would they know all the details of what they are saying yes to? You need to see a complete contract for that.

Comment: I had a grad school colleague who accepted an offer from a corporate lab some months before they would defend their thesis, signed and everything. Some months went by, the company reorganized/changed priorities, and the group they were hired into was axed. They got a nice letter from the company explaining the situation, that there was not job to come to, as well as a check (in essence, severance pay). They restarted their job search and found another position. Wasn't during Covid though...

Comment: @Sverre Many of us in the US do not have a "signed work contract". I don't have a piece of paper that states that the offer I had accepted has actually been converted to an actual job contract. I do have an employee card and the university pays my salary every month, so I am legally an employee, but I don't have a piece of paper that says so.

Comment: @Sverre in some countries in Europe (Netherlands, Belgium, Germany (partially), Denmark), a lot of jobs in academia have standardized conditions (wages, vacation days, bonuses) so there is nothing to negotiate. All the details of standard contracts are publically available. And accepting an offer via email is also not uncommon.